# Facebook Instant Articles inline styles

Tags: facebook, facebook-instant-articles

Can I have inline styles for Facebook Instant Articles articles? I have looked for it on their [documentation for design guides](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/guides/design), they didn't specify if we can or cannot. I know with Google AMP, we were not able to use it, I am not sure if the same applies here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that no we cannot add inline styles, however, we can wrap those elements with `<iframe>` and apply inline styles to those elements and FB will pick it up. E.g:

```
<iframe> <div style="background: red; color: red">Text on Red</div></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/sdk/transformer-rules#rule-context

It is stated there as a comment

> For example, to render text bold in an Instant Article, the  tag must be used. But if your content makes use of  as a means to stylize text bold, you would find that your source markup is valid HTML, but ultimately is not valid Instant Articles markup.

So `<strong>` yields bold text, and `<em>` yields italic. But it seems like more than that cannot be done